# Save Data generated by PCLCRYPTO

Tags: c#, android, windows, windows-phone

I'm using PCLCRYPTO. I need to save the information in a text file in Windows to be retrieved on Android and Windows Phone.

The Encrypt function returns in Bytes and I would like to save the information in a text file to be retrieved on the other devices.

Would anyone know how to turn the bytes into text and what to write to the file to be recovered from the other devices?

The functions are:

```
public static byte[] EncryptAes(string data, string password, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey(password, salt);

    ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
    ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
    var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symetricKey, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    return bytes;
}

public static string DecryptAes(byte[] data, string password, byte[] salt)
{
    byte[] key = CreateDerivedKey(password, salt);

    ISymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider aes = WinRTCrypto.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithm.AesCbcPkcs7);
    ICryptographicKey symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
    var bytes = WinRTCrypto.CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(symetricKey, data);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you get a string in the decrypt method.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
```

Just save the string you get from the bytes in a text file.